# Window scroll with div extist, after ajax loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll

I have realy strange problem and I don't know why it doens't work.

In my website http://www.wytworniaprojektu.eu I use ajax content load (via jQuery .load()) and I need make scroll function only for homepage. Now it works fine but as you see this function execute always for all pages.

What i did:

I add class 'hide-m' to #all-ajax for homepage. Later I build function:

```
if ($(".hide-m").length > 0 ) {
   $(window).scroll(function () {
   var y = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (y > 100) {
   $('#top-header').show();
   } 
   else {
   $('#top-header').hide();
   }
 });
}
else {
  $('#top-header').show();
}
```

I've tired put it inside dom ready and inside ajaxComplete (to recognize if 'hide-m' exists) and nothing change, scroll show / hide #top-header work for all pages?

Any idea, whera I made mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery waypoints over binding the scroll to the window.

```
if ($('.hide-m').length > 0 ) {    
$('.item1').waypoint({handler: function() {
     $('#top-header').toggleClass('show-item');
    },
     offset: '25%'
    });
}
```